# sfdx-cli can output json. Is the output documented anywhere?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Running a `sfdx` command with the json flag will return different json output depending on the command.  Here is an example of the kind of output returned from `sfdx force:package:version:create ... --json`:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "Id": "abc123",
    "Status": "Success",
    "Package2Id": "abc234",
    "Package2VersionId": "abc345",
    "SubscriberPackageVersionId": "abc456",
    "Tag": null,
    "Branch": null,
    "Error": [],
    "CreatedDate": "2020-08-08 12:00",
    "HasMetadataRemoved": false
  }
}
```

Is there any documentation for the json output of these commands?

As far as I can tell the properties in `result` will be different for each command.  It would also be really useful, per command, to know what the range of possible `Status` values are.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally documented in the context of the CLI command (output of x command), but you can usually find more information based on the underlying objects it's interacting with.

For example, the command `force:package:version:create...` is utilizing [Package2VersionCreateRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_package2versioncreaterequest.htm). Within that you can see the following values defined for `Status` that it can contain

> The status of the Package2Version creation request. Valid values
> include:
>
> - Queued
> - InProgress
> - Success
> - Error

Sadly, that isn't actually the full values. Below are a list of all values as of 5/2023.

- Queued
- Initializing
- Verifying Features and Settings
- Verifying Dependencies
- Verifying Metadata
- Finalizing PackageVersion
- Success
- Error

Comment: I am also looking for the reference. I have observed other statuses such as `Initializing`

Comment: Thanks for the hint there's more as I was taking the doc at their word. I found no public references (but I am internal now) so I edited my answer to include the list of values.

Comment: Fantastic - now we just need all of the other command output statuses - preferably formatted as sample json :)